# Building MySQL++ under Cygwin fails to locate the MySQL client library

Tags: c++, mysql, cygwin

I'm trying to build MySQL++ under Cygwin.

According [its documentation](https://github.com/rpetrich/mysqlpp/blob/master/README-Cygwin.txt):

> Before you can build MySQL++, you need to install the
>   libmysqlclient-devel package with Cygwin's setup.exe.

So, I installed this package and those required by it. The only libraries created are (as you can see [in this link](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibmysqlclient-devel%2Flibmysqlclient-devel-10.1.19-1&grep=mysql)):

```
2016-11-10 08:59      702424 usr/lib/libmysqlclient.dll.a
2016-11-10 09:16           0 usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dll.a -> libmysqlclient.dll.a
```

Then I run `./configure` to generate a `Makefile`.

However, it fails because it cannot find MySQL client libraries. The `configure` script says:

```
checking for MySQL library directory... configure: error: Didn't find
mysqlclient library in '/usr/lib64 /usr/lib /usr/lib64/mysql
/usr/lib/mysql /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/mysql 
/usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql /usr/mysql/lib/mysql 
/opt/mysql/lib /opt/mysql/lib/mysql /sw/lib /sw/lib/mysql'
```

Digging into the `configure` file, I can see:

```
do
    if test -d "$m" && \
        (test -f "$m/lib$MYSQL_C_LIB_NAME.so" || \
         test -f "$m/lib$MYSQL_C_LIB_NAME.a")
    then
        MYSQL_C_LIB_DIR=$m
        break
    fi
done
```

So, it looks for a shared library or static library, but `libmysqlclient-devel` didn't install either of those, only an import library (dll.a).

Nevertheless, the MySQL client libraries do work. I can run a simple C program to connect and retrieve data from my MySQL server with flags: `-I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib  -lmysqlclient`, and it works perfectly.

So, any hint? Do you know how can I build MySQL++ without building the MySQL client libraries from the MySQL source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it fails because it cannot find MySQL client libraries.

Apparently the library naming scheme changed on Cygwin since the last time it was successfully tried.

I've released version 3.2.3 to fix this. (I'm MySQL++'s maintainer.)

Incidentally, the GitHub page you linked to is just someone's mirror of the source code. MySQL++'s home page is [here](http://tangentsoft.com/mysql++/).

Comment: I finally downloaded MySQL source code and build it to generate `.dll` library. Then, I could build MySQL++ without problems. 
Nevertheless, I'll try to download your new release. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. However I still have the issue that it's not able to locate `cygmysqlpp-3.dll` when I run executable. It's compiled: `g++ -o testConnection testConnection.cpp -I /usr/local/include/mysql++  -L /usr/local/lib  -lmysqlpp  $(/usr/bin/mysql_config --cflags --libs)`. The only way to make it work, is copying `.dll` in same path where is executable. I guess is it a normal behavior to run under cygwin, isn't it?